# Creating multiple empty files in a loop python

Tags: python

i was wondering if there was a way to create 10 empty files in a a specific directory while using a loop in python. I need to create the files with the names test1.txt, test2.txt, all the way up to test10.txt. I am pretty new to python, so any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Here is what i am working with.

```
def createFiles()
    lab3='/home/student/Lab3'
    #Before creation of files
    dir_list = os.listdir(lab3)
    print("List of directories before creating files")
    print(dir_list)
    print()
    
    with open('test1.text', 'w'):
        pass
    #After creation of files
    dir_list=os.listdir(lab3)
    print("Directory and files after file creation: ")
    print(dir_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just place your call to `open` inside a loop:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    with open(f'test{i}.txt', 'w'):
        pass
```

`range` is used to generate a sequence of integers; it's start inclusive and end exclusive so `range(1,11)` yields integers 1 to 10. The [`f` string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) within `open` provides a nice way to place variables in strings.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do what you want to do in a single line:

```
for i in range(10): open(f'/tmp/test{i+1}.text', 'w').close()
```

If you want to create files when they don't exist, but not blow away the contents of any file that already exists, just use `a` instead of `w`.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple and easy in python.

```
#counting starts from 0
for i in range(10):
    i+=1
    with open(f"test{i}.txt","w"):
        pass
```

[F-String in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/)

Comment: Cleaner would be `with open(f"test{i+1}.txt","w"):` and get rid of the `i+=1` line.

Answer (score 0):

Your style is ok, but needs a bit of modification in your code. I corrected your code. Please see below:

```
import os
def createFiles():
    lab3 = '/home/student/Lab3'
    lab3 = 'F:\ProjectWorks\Python\pythonCore\PythonPractice\MyFolder\MyFolder2'
    # Before creation of files
    dir_list = os.listdir(lab3)
    print("List of directories before creating files")
    print(dir_list)
    print()

    os.chdir(lab3)

    for i in range(1, 11):
        with open(f'test{i}.txt', 'w'):
            pass
    # After creation of files
    dir_list = os.listdir(lab3)
    print("Directory and files after file creation: ")
    print(dir_list)

createFiles()
```

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is;

```
files = 10
for file_name in range(files):
     file = open(‘test’+str(file_name)+'.txt', ‘w’)
     file.close()
```

This will make 10 blank files

Comment: That actually doesn't quite do what was requested.

Comment: @Steve What seems to be the issue? I ran it again, and it created files0.txt through to file9.txt. If you want 1 - 10, enter `file = open('test'+str(file_name)+'.txt', 'w')` instead

Comment: At the time I wrote my comment, you weren't adding `.txt` to the end of the filename.  I see that you've since added that.  It still isn't technically quite right, but now it's much better.